# How to do pending spec inside Yesod specs

Tags: haskell, yesod, hspec

I'm new to Yesod and I'm trying to add a pending spec within a `withApp` block (at the moment I'm just trying to modify the spec generated by the Yesod scaffholding).

the code looks like :

appSpec :: Spec
   appSpec :: withApp $ do
     describe "getMyHandlerR" $ do
       it "todo" $ do
          pending

But I got the following error message :

```
Couldn't match type ‘(App, wai-3.2.0:Network.Wai.Middleware)’
               with ‘()’
Expected type: SpecWith (TestApp App)
  Actual type: SpecWith (Arg Expectation)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: it "todo" $ do { pending }
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘do { it "todo" $ do { pending } }’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  describe "upload a file without error"
  $ do { it "todo" $ do { pending } }
```

If I remove the `withApp` everything works. I understand `withApp` is changing somehow the expected type but how come `describe` and `it` have the correct type whereas `pending` doesn't ?

Comment: I think you just need to throw away the `TestApp App` argument via `it "todo" $ \_ -> pending` or `it "todo" $ const pending`

Comment: I can confirm @MichaelSnoyman's fix works

Comment: Wow, it works indeed. I tried `liftIO` but without success. I'm still surprised that `it "" pending`  works outside of `withApp` but doesn't inside, there is probably some type inference magic there. @MichaelSnoyman could you post is as an answer so I can accept it ? Wouldn't it be worth doing adding a `ypending` or equivalent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying my comment to an answer:

I think you just need to throw away the `TestApp App` argument via:

```
it "todo" $ \_ -> pending
```

or

```
it "todo" $ const pending
```

> Wouldn't it be worth doing adding a `ypending` or equivalent?

Sounds like a good idea to me, I've actually never personally used `pending` which is why I'd never thought of it. Would you be able to send a PR to get that included?

Comment: I'm happy to do a pull request for it. However should it be ypending like yit ? I still don't understand why normal pending dosenst work in a normal it block ( not a yit block)

Comment: Because the type of `pending` is `Expectation`, which is `IO ()`, not allowing for the extra argument. I don't fully understand the type magic in hspec, but it is present.

Comment: I had a look and it's more tricky that I thought. doing `ypending = const pending` doesn't work in a `yit` context which anyway I'm not using. I understand enough of `yit` to do anything at the moment.IThere are type families involved in Hspec, which explains the magic. It might possible to modify `withApp` from the scaffolding to accept pending without the const.

Comment: this is a more general issue than OPs that I fought with for a few hours, trying to get App-independent tests to work, and it'd be useful for my fellow Yesod newbies to have access to this in testing-relevant documentation, if possible!

Answer (score 1):

This works like a charm for me with latest Yesod:

```
it "should x" $ do
  liftIO pending
```